How might I scan a Swift module for a list of types used in it?
We have certain types in our code that store personal information (such as Name, DateOfBirth, PhoneNumber, etc).
We would like to be able to find how our modules "make use" of these types. "Making use" would encompass:

Defining any types that nest these types.
Defining any functions that take, return, or use these types.
Calling any functions that take or return these types.

This would then let us generate a report about which personal types each module uses.
Is there some automatic way to collect this from compiler or query it from Xcode's tooling? If we can find all types made use of by a module we could filter for just the canonical list of personal information types we care about.

Would that include any internal or private types that use them?

@JeremyP I think, ideally, yes it would include those. However, if it only included public types this could also be helpful and any lead in this direction would be very helpful – thanks.

I don't have an answer but Xcode does have the ability to search for references to a type so it probably does exist. You might be able to do it with SourceKit

thanks @JeremyP, that sounds worth a look!
